# control y-axis title positions when combining several plots with patchwork package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to be able to control the y-axis title position for each plot with respect to the y-axis itself, so that when I input differing antibiotic name lengths into the top plot, the y-axis title in the bottom plot is the same distance from the y-axis and I do not have to manually change this in the bottom plot everytime I change the antiobiotic names in the top plot. Anyone able to help?

The first plot shows the default without any adjustment.

The second plot shows the desired distance the y-axis title should be from the y-axis labels.

The third plot demonstates how varying the antibiotic name length in top plot means the correction needs to be changed. I would like to try to code this to happen automatically.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

therapy_1 <- tibble(
  antibiotic = c("IV Piperacillin-tazobactam", "IV Piperacillin-tazobactam"),
  time_point = c("start", "end"),
  date = c("2023-04-10","2023-04-25")) %>% 
  mutate(date = as_date(date))

therapy_2 <-tibble(
  antibiotic = c("PO co-trimoxazole", "PO co-trimoxazole"),
  time_point = c("start", "end"),
  date = c("2023-04-10","2023-04-25")) %>% 
  mutate(date = as_date(date))

inflammatory_markers <- tibble(
  date = c("2023-04-10", "2023-04-12"),
  value = c("38.1", "37.8")) %>%
  mutate(date = as_date(date))

p1 <- therapy_1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = antibiotic, colour = antibiotic)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p2 <- therapy_2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = antibiotic, colour = antibiotic)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

default <- inflammatory_markers %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = value))

desired <- inflammatory_markers %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = value)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = -160)))

# default output
p1 / default
```

[image]

```r
# desired output
p1 / desired
```

[image]

```r
# when length of y-axis labels shortened
p2 / desired
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I assume you meant "title" and not "label" - I have allowed myself to change this in the question title.

Comment: yes I did, sorry; I've changed it

Comment: would you care showing a desired output, e.g. with a sketch? I am really not quite sure that I understand what you would like to achieve

Comment: I've reconstructed the question again to try to make it clearer what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The cowplot package is of course an excellent package and I can only recommend using it. One last comment: I think maybe you wanna rethink your visualisation. If your antibiotic is always a line (maybe indicating duration of treatment?), then another option would be to use direct labelling instead. Here, the geomtextpath package gives amazing options, you could then label the line directly, and save yourself the hassle with weird y title optics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different enough to merit a second answer (IMO). If you're happy to use another package, you can also use `egg::ggarrange` which should do exactly what you need.

```r
library(egg)

ggarrange(p1, desired)
```

[image]

```r
ggarrange(p2, desired)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much. using another package seems to be the most sensible option. also prompted me to go look at `cowplot` which I haven't used before either and specifically discusses this very issue (https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/aligning_plots.html). Think I will go with `egg` for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually not exactly trivial (with patchwork). The solution which I am suggesting would also not be perfect. I think the easiest hack would be to use a custom annotation as your y axis title instead of a real y axis title. It is not perfect, because the size of the plots still vary and the annotation position will be located depending on your x scale.

```r
## adding a custom annotation to your inferior panel. 
desired <-
  inflammatory_markers %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = value)) +
  ## annotate with geom_text and not annotate, because you are using dates
  ## and you want to use "nudge_x" which doesn't work with annotate
  geom_text(
    data = data.frame(), aes(
      label = "value",
      x = min(inflammatory_markers$date),
      y = 1.5
    ),
    angle = 90, nudge_x = -.4
  ) +
  ## limit coordinates and turn clipping off
  coord_cartesian(xlim = range(inflammatory_markers$date), clip = "off") +
  ## remove y label
  labs(y = NULL)

# default output
p1 / desired
```

[image]

```r
p2 / desired
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: or whatever plot you wanna stick together. You get the idea. (if both show lines, as in my example, then best to use facets)

Comment: thanks but aligning them "left justified" so to speak wasn't quite the problem I was encountering. If you remove all the `margin` or `vjust` arguments, "left justified" is actually the default. I am trying to get the axis title closer to the axis in the lower plot, as in therapy plot 1, but if you then have shorter y-axis labels in the upper plot, as in therapy plot 2, your manual adjustement either with `margin` or `vjust` isn't correct

Comment: @Ollie would you care showing a desired output, e.g. with a sketch? I am really not quite sure that I understand what you mean